# Count Orders for Store by Date

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, mysql

I am creating a simple script to count items ordered in a multi-store Magento installation and display the results in a webpage. I have written something that correctly counts all ordered items.

I now wish to narrow this down and count only certain product ids for certain store ids. How can I target specific columns from $results?

```
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$dateToday = date('Y-m-d');
$noDays = 1;

for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $pastWeek = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$noDays.' days', strtotime($dateToday)));
    $noDays++;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_order_item` WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN '".$pastWeek." 00:00:00' AND '".$pastWeek." 23:59:59'";
    $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($results as $value) {

        //something like - if (store id == 1) { if (product id == 2 || 3) { $j++; } else {

$j++;
        }
        echo "Date: ".$pastWeek." | Quantity Sold: ".$j."<br />";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento have a ***resource collection model*** for `sales_flat_order_item` table means sales items collection.
if you want to filter  the sales items then you can use  `addAttributeToFilter()`

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection');
```

By using this resource model you *`can filters,group by table columns`* *`store_id,product_id,created_at`* of that collection.

***For getting a collection of particular date interval, you can try below example***

> ```
> $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('product_id');
> $collection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('gteq' =>'1994-10-24'));
> $collection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('lteq' => $dateToday));
> ```

**Use getSelect()->group('FieldName') to collection.**

*Example:*

```
$collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.product_id');
```

For getting `the count of that collection`  use **count()** function.

```
echo $dateToday = date('Y-m-d');
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('product_id');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('gteq' =>'1994-10-24'));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('lteq' => $dateToday));


echo $collection->count();
```

For getting more details abount filter check out
https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Using+Magento+1.x+collections